# Has anybody implemented rosserial_client-based node in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: ros, serial, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the pi board as a client board as if it were an Arduino board connected to PC/laptop, and I'm wondering if anybody has ever done that. If so, could you tell me what libraries you used it?

With regards to rosserial_embeddedlinux, I need to download the development environment in my server-side host, which is Jetson, and in most of the cases IDEs are not able to be installed in Jetson platform. So I would rather write the implementation code for Hardware class (wiki.ros.org/rosserial_client/Tutorials/Adding Support for New Hardware) so that the rosserial-based connection for Raspberry Pi is established. Could anybody please help me with this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272599/has-anybody-implemented-rosserial_client-based-node-in-raspberry-pi?/) by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2017-10-09**:
Hi,
sorry, where is the use case for this ?
All your boards have ip available over serial, ethernet or wifi. I think you have all you need available.
I see one case only to use ros_serial: small limitted system without ip.
Thanks for more
Cheers
Chrimo

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2017-10-09**:
@ChriMo Actually, rosserial is able to use TCP/IP, so one can use it on a system that has an IP link but you cannot install ROS (ex. Windows, small embedded Linux (too small for Boost...)).
In that case, for the Raspberry Pi, rosserial_embeddedlinux seems OK.

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2017-10-09**:
OK, I understand now. Like my OSX.
Thanks for more :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to use [rosserial_embeddedlinux](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_embeddedlinux) directly on the Raspberry Pi.

I did not use it myself yet but you can either use a serial link or an IP link through TCP/IP.

See the tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_embeddedlinux/Tutorials

First, generate the header files for the messages with the `make_libraries.py` script on your Ubuntu computer, then copy them on the Raspberry Pi and build your rosserial node with CMake.

---

Originally posted by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) with karma: 544 on 2017-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on 2017-11-17**:
As I am also developing a Raspbian/Linux c++ client application (i.e. not arduino) running an a RaspI3, and maybe as it is with this author, the rosserial_embeddedlinux/make_libraries.py contains references to arduino, which doesn't seem correct.  I note the mbed example does't contain arduino text.

**Comment by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on 2017-11-19**:
With further investigation, there is a make_library.py file under rosserial/rosserial_client with no arduino refererences, i.e. presumably to generate generic c++ libraries for use on a non-ROS Linux controller such as Raspberry Pi. Is that correct? It won't run however on my Kinetic workstation.

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2017-11-20**:
Exactly, rosserial_embeddedlinux uses rosserial_client + adds the communication part and some examples. The references to Arduino in the python script are only a badly named variable.
I have tried to run the example HelloROS on a RaspberryPi and it works like a charm.

**Comment by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on 2017-11-20**:
Sry, a necessary correction to prev. comment. A "no arduino" make_libraries.py under /rosserial/rosserial_client/scripts runs & generates a set of ROS files in a designated directory. I presume I would add ros.h, embedded_linux_comms.c, embedded_linux hardware.h files to use on a Linux Raspberry Pi?

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2017-11-20**:
Yes, you can, but the easier it to run: `rosrun rosserial_embeddedlinux make_libraries.py .`
It will generate a  `ros_lib` directory with the embeddedlinux specific files already inside and a `examples` one.
You can then move the files to RPi  and `g++ -o HelloROS HelloROS.cpp -I../../ros_lib`